# Create folder in Apps exe. is

Tags: visual-studio-2010, error-handling, path, directory

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I want to create a folder to store images in my app.

This is code I am trying to use.

```
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath \ "quilt_images")) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath \ "quilt_images")
    End If
```

I am getting error

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Conversion from string "C:\Users\DaD\Documents\Visual St" to type 'Long' is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

`If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath \ "quilt_images")) Then`

you're dividing, not concatenating the string.